# Link data from sql from 2/3 columns

Tags: sql

I don't know if the question title is so clear, but here is my question:

I had table UsersMovements which contains Users along with their movements

UsersMovements:

```
ID
UserID
MovementID
Comments
Time/Date
```

I need help looking for a query which would give me if users 1, 2 & 3 had been in a common MovementID, knowing that I don't know what is the MovementID

The real case is that, I want to see if those X users which I would select been in an area (in a limited interval, assuming I had date/Time in the table)

Thank you

Comment: Your question is not clear because you specify two questions ("I need help . .  " and then "The real case is").  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I guess you can take a look on INTERSECT-operator,but please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select list of movements which have userid 1,2 and 3 you can use group by with having

select movementid
from usermovements
where userid in(1,2,3)
group by movementid
having count(distinct userid)=3

Comment: With this query, then I could know that those users 1, 2 & 3 have exactly the same movementID  (which could be more than one), right?

Comment: All the movementid for user 1,2 and 3